# In localhost my laravel vue.js site perfectly working but when published on serve it doesn't work vue.js correctly if else condition

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a laravel vuejs project. In localhost, every query retrieved data and vue.js if-else condition work perfectly but when I upload my full project on the live server then data retrieved correctly but the if-else condition doesn't work

Here is my code:

```
                  <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
                    <b>Relation <i class="fa fa-heart pink"></i></b>
                    <a class="float-right" v-if="user.relation_id != null"> 
                      <span>{{ user.relation.name }}</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
```

What's the problem here? please suggest me any brother

Comment: Use vuejs devtools to check whether all your local variable has been populated properly. Check "users" is having value in it.

Comment: first check if usr is available or not like you can try this way  v-if="user && user.relation_id != null">......i think your user is not logged in thats why it creates the problem

Comment: Brother after login, I have checked the users array and I saw array values but relation_id is null that's why I included this condition here